# how to uncheckout a checked in directory in clearcase

Tags: clearcase, cleartool

I have checked out a directory, modified some files and checked in the directory
Is there a way to revert back the checked in directory  and start with original directory

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Never delete a version, this is way too dangerous (in that it removes all metadata, and hyperlinks attached to it).

Do a **subtractive merge**, in order to cancel the contributions recorded in your last directory version.

See in IBM the articles "[To remove contributions of some versions](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.hlp.doc/cc_main/to_remove_contrib.htm)".
You can see an example of a `cleartool merge -delete` in "[Undo remove file in ClearCase](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4634265/6309)"

Answer (score -1):

You may try to delete the version. In the version tree, right-click the bubble of the current version and choose "delete". The version tree will automatically refresh and fail to do so, because the version it tries to display does not exist anymore. After an update you should see the old version.

If you have edited multiple files, you will have to do this for each file. I haven't found a way to do this by command line, but then again I haven't looked thoroughly ;)