# Recover version tree on removed directory

Tags: version-control, clearcase, clearcase-ucm

I'm working with clearcase 8.0.1.17

I removed a directory containing 4 other directory with multiples files :

- `DirA`

  - `DirA1` (5 files)
  - `DirA2` (10 files)
  - `DirA3` (4 files)
  - `DirA4` (15 files)

I checked in this and made a baseline. Now I want to recover `DirA` with only  `DirA2`. I recreated both directory with the 10 files from my backup but I've lost all the versions trees.

How can I do to recover version trees ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot just recreate the folder/files, or you would create [evil twins](https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/node/722477) (elements with the same name but different history/version tree): you can [list evil twins here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11705099/6309).

You need to delete your new elements, and open the version tree of the **parent folder of DirA**.
You will see a version tree like:

```
 n-3 (list DirA)
 n-2 (delete DirA)
 n-1 (import new DirA folder: evil twins)
 n   (delete DirA again)
```

You can then merge the n-3 version (which listed DirA) to the current (where you deleted `DirA`)
That will restore the subfolder entry DirA.

Repeat that for version tree of DirA itself (that will restore the DirAx folder entries)

Full details in "[How to restore an element that has been rmnamed](https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/how-restore-element-has-been-rmnamed)", but here the idea is: do that for the *folders* first.
Then the files if needed.

See also "[Undo remove file in ClearCase](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4634373/6309)", using [`cleartool ln`](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSH27_9.0.1/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_ln.htm).